# JGit authorization problems [Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/ ... .git: not authorized]

Tags: java, git, authorization, jgit

My very-very simple test code always fails. I cannot get access to my own repository (PRIVATE) (it is completely new and empty). The username and password are perfectly working I tested signing in and out several times. I went through several StackOverflow posts, but still no clue what can cause the problem. I have tired two different ways, **first clone the repo (give the credentials at that point) and then push**. My second try was to **create a repo commit something than push (give the credentials at this point)**. None of these worked.

JGit error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/USERNAME/testing.git: not authorized
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:191)
```

Java code (First way):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws GitAPIException, IOException {

        CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider
                = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider( "XXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXX" );
        Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
                .setURI( "XXXXXXXXXX" )
                .setDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "git_test"))
                .setCredentialsProvider( credentialsProvider )
                .call();

        File file = new File( git.getRepository().getWorkTree(), "file" + new Object().hashCode() );
        file.createNewFile();
        git.add().addFilepattern( file.getName() ).call();
        git.commit().setMessage( "Add file " + file.getName() ).call();

        git.push()
                .setCredentialsProvider( credentialsProvider )
                .call();
    }
}
```

Java code (Second way):

```
this.git = Git.init().setDirectory(new File(folderPath)).call();

this.git.add().addFilepattern("temp.txt").call();
        this.git.commit().setMessage("Modified temp.txt").call();

this.git.push().setRemote(textfield.getText())
               .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("XXXXXXX", "XXXXXX"))
               .call();
```

Do you have any clue what is going on?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Github:
"*For developers, if you are using a password to authenticate Git operations with GitHub.com today, you must begin using a personal access token over HTTPS (recommended) or SSH key by August 13, 2021, to avoid disruption. If you receive a warning that you are using an outdated third-party integration, you should update your client to the latest version.*" [Described here](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/#what-you-need-to-do-today)

Thus, I had to generate a token, what I did the following way:
[A personal access token (classic) generation...](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

After, in the setCredentialsProvider() method I gave the following:

```
.setCredentialsProvider( new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider( "<token>", "" ) );
```

Password must be left empty, just give the token and that's it.